# What's the most elegant way to copy just one file with gradle

Tags: gradle

What's the most concise and most elegant and the shortest way to copy just one file AND rename it with gradle?

So far I could think of just this:

```
copy {
    from projectDir
    into projectDir
    include '.env.template'
    rename '.env.template', '.env'
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simplify your [`CopySpec`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html):

```
copy {
    from file('.env.template')
    into projectDir
    rename '.*', '.env'
}
```

The `from` method accepts single `File` objects and, since only this one file is copied, the `rename` pattern can match any copied file.

This way is simple and clean, but to follow the Gradle concept, you should consider using a [`Copy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Copy.html) task, to maintain a clean cut between *configuration* and *execution* phase.

**Edit:**

I just learned, that one can provide a closure for the `rename` method, so you could also use:

```
copy {
    // ...
    rename { '.env' }
}
```

Comment: "follow the Gradle concept" - how would I call this Copy task from my task then?

Comment: By depending on it. Tasks are only called explicitly via command line, all other task execution is managed by Gradle internally by building a dependency tree. If you have a task (e.g. of type `Jar`) and it is required to copy a file before each execution of the task, you simply add a dependency via `dependsOn myCopyTask` to its configuration closure.

Comment: @SergeiLedvanov I just finished struggling with it and only can say is `"Just put the copy task in your build.gradle (I put it on the bottom) and then Gradle will execute automagically"`.

Answer (score -1):

```
task copySingleFileInGradle {
   doFirst {
      def src = new File("sourcefile")        // this must exist in top-level project dir
      def dst = new File("destinationFile")   // this will get created when task is run
      dst.write(src.text)
   }
}
```